# How can i access Array declared in one switch case and use it in another switch case C++

Tags: c++, arrays

Im trying to create a menu driven program to perform operations on an array , I'm trying to figure out how to access variables from one switch statement to another. [I am a noob]

This is the program

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   int c,a=0;
   do
   {
       cout << "-----MENU------" << endl;
       cout << "1.Create" << endl;
       cout << "2.Display" << endl;
       cout << "3.Insert" << endl;
       cout << "4.Delete" << endl;
       cout << "5.Search" << endl;
       cout << "6.Exit" << endl;
       cin >> c;

       switch(c)
    {
        case 1:
        {
            cout << "Enter the size of array :";
            int s;
            cin >> s;
            a=s;
            int myarray[s];
            for(int i=0;i<s;i++)
            {
                cout<<"Enter "<<i+1<<" element :";
                cin>>myarray[i];
            }
        }
        case 2:
        {
            if(a==0)
            {
              cout<<"Array is empty"<<endl;
            }
            else()

        }
        case 3:
        {

        }
    }
    }while(1);
```

Comment: Your next problem will be that you're missing `break;` at the end of each case, unless you want each one to flow to the next.

Comment: The issue is the scope of myarray. Its defined in the block inside the curly braces under the case for 1, and is therefore not visible to the block under the case of 2. You should define it next to a, above the do statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first problem is that `int array[s];` is not legal C++. It's a *variable length array* which is legal in C but not in C++. The C++ solution is to use a [vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> array;
switch (c)
{
case 1:
{
    cout << "Enter the size of array :";
    int s;
    cin >> s;
    array.resize(s);
    ...
}
case 2:
    if (array.empty())
    {
        cout<<"Array is empty"<<endl;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: It is probably worth noting that several C++ compilers support variable-length arrays as an extension. My guess is that OP is probably using such a compiler. However, even if this is the case, you are right that a variable-length array is not appropriate in this situation, as they cannot be resized.